# Сохранение настроек в виде массива

Tags: android, java

Каким образом, используя [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), сохранить массив данных? Единственный метод для работы с набором настроек - это `getStringSet (String, Set<String>)`. Но мне нужно сохранять порядок элементов в массиве между сеансами. Как я понял, метод `getStringSet` не гарантирует сохранения порядка элементов.

Comment: Он просто не предназначен для этого. Но если очень сильно хочется, то вы можете закодировать свой массив байтов (или что-то у вас там) в BASE64 или просто как-нибудь превратить в строку и положить туда.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я решал вопрос в лоб и просто. Допустим у меня есть массив `a[]`, который надо сохранить:

```
int[] a;
//...
SharedPreferences settings=context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("MyArraySize", a.length); //пишем размер массива
for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
    editor.putInt("MyArray"+i, a[i]); //складываем элементы массива
editor.commit();
```

Теперь читаем:

```
settings=context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES, 0);       
int size=settings.getInt("MyArraySize", 0); //читаем размер массива
if(i==0)
   return;
int[] a=new int[size]; //аллоцируем массив
for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
    a[i]=settings.getInt("MyArray"+i, 0); //заполняем элементы массива
```

В общем идея ясна - немного коряво, но зато работает.

Comment: как вариант, идея та же - только, сохранять 1 строчку и вытягивать одну строчку, а потом уже парсить в массив, любым удобным способом

Comment: Я решил использовать совет @Barmaley. А вариант от @Gorets тоже заработал с использованием JSON.